# Dynamic type dereferrencing?

Tags: c++, c, dynamic

In attempting to answer another question, I was intrigued by a bout of curiousity, and wanted to find out if an idea was possible.

- Is it possible to *dynamically* dereference either a void * pointer (we assume it points to a valid referenced dynamically allocated copy) or some other type during run time to return the correct type?
- Is there some way to store a supplied type (as in, the class knows the void * points to an int), if so how?
- Can said stored type (if possible) be used to dynamically dereference?
- Can a type be passed on it's own as an argument to a function?

Generally the concept (no code available) is a doubly-linked list of void * pointers (or similar) that can dynamically allocated space, which also keep with them a copy of what type they hold for later dereference.

Comment: Are you in C++ or C? They're very different languages and trying both spouts ignorance.

Comment: I'm looking for solutions from either. This is a concept. Difference is arguable but this question isn't the place for that (I am sure there have been numerous that state C and C++ before...).

Comment: Both languages are statically typed so in general, no.  Otherwise, you'd have to include some metadata with your objects to help facilitate identifying what types they are.  That might not be a desirable option.

Comment: [faq#dontask]: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." // apart from that, think about the languages like JavaScript, Perl, Ruby etc. that you can do type manipulations at runtime (including modifying types) - many  have their runtimes implemented in C or C++. So: is it possible? Yes. But you're building a different language.

Comment: @Jeff Including metadata is an acceptable option.

Comment: @Mat It is a problem I face (or rather, will face). Questions are answerable (even with a yes/no). I built my own version some time ago but it relied on the user to dereference (which could cause issues if it's done incorrectly).

Comment: @SSight3: your question is also overly broad IMO. C and C++ are different languages, not least with respect to types.

Comment: @Mat: True, but I don't anticipate many solutions for an any doubly-linked list with dynamic dereferencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Dynamic references:

No. Instead of having your variables hold just pointers, have them hold a struct containing both the actual pointer and a tag defining what type the pointer is pointing to

```
struct Ref{
    int tag;
    void *ref;
};
```

and then, when "dereferencing", first check the tag to find out what you want to do.

---

2) Storing types in your variables, passing them to functions.

This doesn't really make sense, as types aren't values that can be stored around. Perhaps what you just want is to pass around a class / constructor function and that is certainly feasible.

---

In the end, C and C++ are bare-bones languages. While a variable assignment in a dynamic language looks a lot like a variable assignment in C (they are just a `=` after all) in reality the dynamic language is doing a lot of extra stuff behind the scenes (something it is allowed to do, since a new language is free to define its semantics)

Comment: Is there any good reason to pass around `void*` in C++, like in your `Ref` struct (except for legacy code or interfacing C functions)? Either use dynamic binding with an interface ABC or templates. I find `void*` is *C-thinking leaking into C++*.

Comment: I could see myself passing lots of void*s around if I ever needed to make my own programing language/compiler. The question seemed more theoretical anyway and I feel using as examples instances where C++ is the one doing fancy stuff behind the scenes for you would kind of miss the point.

Comment: @missingno: I've never quite figured, but when you use typecasting (like (int)A), it must be passing something to somewhere, and I wonder if it's possible to get that something it passes. Or to put it differently: How does the compiler tell an int from a char? But yes, theoretical (hoping to make it somehow a reality). Doesn't boost offer something like this?

Comment: C is statically typed so it knows at compile time wether a variable is an int or a char. Because of this, whenever said variable is used, it knows if it needs to generate the int code path or the char code path. As for typecasts, the ones you mention are actually conversions (with nifty syntax) and the compiler also knows how to handle all of them beforehand. Boost and other high level C++ template hackery are a whole new world.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is not really possible in C++ due to lack of type reflection and lack of dynamic binding. Dynamic dereferencing is especially impossible due to these.

You could try to emulate its behavior by storing types as enums or `std::type_info*` pointers, but these are far from practical. They require registration of types, and huge switch..case or if..else statements every time you want to do something with them. A common container class and several wrapper classes might help achieving them (I'm sure this is some design pattern, any idea of its name?)

You could also use inheritance to solve your problem if it fits.

Or perhaps you need to reconsider your current design. What exactly do you need this for?